# create app to display website

Tags: windows, macos, google-chrome, firefox

I am looking for a tool to create an app out of a website.

Basically I want to provide two files: `.exe` (win) and `.app` (mac), which both either look for an appropriate browser software on the clients system or use an included version of Firefox or Chrome **to display a website without any GUI from the browser**.

As far as I know, the service [wunderlist](http://www.wunderlist.com) did exactly that: create a responsive website and deliver it on almost every platform as an app by using such a thing. Sadly I was not able to learn more about their way of doing it.

Is there already a project for doing so, or do I have to start from scratch?

Comment: I guess you are trying to display a website (not just the url)? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WebKit to achieve your goal. There are apis in C++, C#, Python and so on...

It is a complete web browser engine. With WebKit you can open a website and display it in your application window.

Check out http://www.webkit.org/

Chrome is based on WebKit.